# Click on "Submit order" to continue payment by PayPal Checkout

Tags: php, jquery, html, paypal

I have made a simple checkout page, when I select payment method (PayPal ) and Submit order is clicked I want to send this to PayPal Direct, pease check this code:

```
 <script>
function pmet(gateway,style) {
    $("#list-group-1 > a").removeClass("active");
    $("#"+style).addClass("active");
    if (gateway == "PayPal") {
        var account = 'PayPal account: <b>admin@me4onkof.info</b>';
    } else if(gateway == "Bitcoin") {
        var account = 'Bitcoin address: <b>1PRPdegR2hZmb5GNb4z6C2xq9APbnBWpUa</b>';
    } else if(gateway == "Skrill") {
        var account = 'Skrill account: <b>Skrill@skrill.com</b>';
    } else if(gateway == "AdvCash") { 
        var account = 'AdvCash account: <b>AdvCash@AdvCash.info</b>';
    } else if(gateway == "Perfect Money") {
        var account = 'Perfect Money account: <b>U9436432</b>';
    } else if(gateway == "OKPay") {
        var account = 'OKPay account: <b>OK740032174</b>';
    } else if(gateway == "Payeer") {
        var account = 'Payeer account: <b>P22031700</b>';
    } else if(gateway == "Western Union") {
        var account = 'Western Union details: <b>NAme , Location: <b>Pakistan, Lahore</b>';
    } else if(gateway == "Moneygram") {
        var account = 'Moneygram details: <b>Name , Location: <b>Pakistan, Lahore</b>';
    } else { }
    if(gateway == "PayPal") {
        var text = 'Click on <b>"Submit order"</b> to continue payment by PayPal Checkout';
    } else {
        var text = 'You need to make payment manually and submit order.</b><br/>Will receive your license code and link to download the software up to 1 hour.<br/><br/>Payment details:<br/>'+account+'<br/>Amount: $35<br/>Description: Order BitExchanger v2.0 Script<br><br><div class="form-group"><label>Transaction number/batch</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="txn_id"></div>';
    }
    $("#pay_via").val(gateway);
    $("#payment_i").html(text);
}
```

```
                    <div class="container mt">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4>Select Payment Method</h4>
                    <div class="list-group" id="list-group-1">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="PayPal" onclick="pmet('PayPal','PayPal');" class="list-group-item"><img src="http://www.exchangesoftware.info/buy/assets/icons/PayPal.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PayPal</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Bitcoin" onclick="pmet('Bitcoin','Bitcoin');" class="list-group-item"><img src="assets/icons/Bitcoin.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Bitcoin</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Skrill" onclick="pmet('Skrill','Skrill');" class="list-group-item"><img src="assets/icons/Skrill.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Skrill</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="AdvCash" onclick="pmet('AdvCash','AdvCash');" class="list-group-item"><img src="assets/icons/AdvCash.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AdvCash</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="PerfectMoney" onclick="pmet('Perfect Money','PerfectMoney');" class="list-group-item"><img src="assets/icons/PerfectMoney.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Perfect Money</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="OKPay" onclick="pmet('OKPay','OKPay');" class="list-group-item"><img src="assets/icons/OKPay.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OKPay</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Payeer" onclick="pmet('Payeer','Payeer');" class="list-group-item"><img src="assets/icons/Payeer.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Payeer</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="WesternUnion" onclick="pmet('Western Union','WesternUnion');" class="list-group-item"><img src="assets/icons/Westernunion.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Western Union</a>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Moneygram" onclick="pmet('Moneygram','Moneygram');" class="list-group-item"><img src="assets/icons/Moneygram.png" width="30px" height="30px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Moneygram</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4>License Information</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Your name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Your email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                        <small>Important: Sometimes hotmail.com and outlook.com skip our emails</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Domains (Eg: exchanger.com,www.exchanger.com)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domains">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="pay_via" id="pay_via">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4>Payment Instruction</h4>
                    <div class="alert alert-info" id="payment_i">
                        Please select payment method.
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="make_order">Submit order</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div><! --/row -->
```

Comment: I believe that you should create a new file (ex. checkout.php) that will receive data from this form. Then let the file redirect to Paypal or another pay method. Use IPN for pays. Ex. Paypal IPN. **WARNING:** All in IPN must be checked. Safety is most important.

Comment: Please any one Can Help me to Create This Code & File

Comment: If you are starting with the creation of applications, it may be difficult to do it safely. Create checkout.php and your form `action` attribute change to: `checkout.php`. From now your form should redirect to checkout.php after submitting. Now open checkout.php file in text editor and you must checked all data in `$_POST` array.

Comment: Check that `$_POST['pay_via']` is equal to 'PayPal' and others too ex. email. Next... If data will be ok you can prepare payment form (for Paypay here is HTML documentation: [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_reference_landing/). When the form will ready you can use jquery to auto-submit form. If your user should get something after payment you must still handle the IPN. Find this in the documentation.

Comment: Friend I have other Paymnets Getway Also
I just want that when someone has clicked on paypal and click on Submit order want   redirect to paypal

Comment: I dont have checkout.php File

Comment: Yes, so i suggest create new file and use it to redirect

Comment: Now i have Create This File : checkout.php

Comment: Please Tell me how i can redirect  Paypal Getway to  checkout.php ?

Comment: You want redirect to Paypal payment page?

Comment: yes please i want

Comment: Here is written what to do: [LINK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_reference_landing/)

Comment: I have to do like This <form action="" method="$_POST['pay_via']">

Comment: Please Help me [link](http://amxmoney.com/HTML/buy.php)